# Spring ModelAndView to RestController json response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a legacy spring code where they use `ModelAndView` and they add the objects to it as below.

```
ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView();
result.addObject("folders", folders);
return result;
```

for the above i am getting response as

```
    {
  "folders": [
    {
      "recordCount": 0,
      "folderContentType": "Reports",
      "folderId": 34,
      },
    {
      "recordCount": 2,
      "folderContentType": "SharedReports",
      "folderId": 88,
      }
  ]
}
```

I have changed these to use Spring's RestController with a POJO backing the results returned from DB.

```
@GetMapping("/folders")
public List<Folder> getAllFolders() {
    return Service.findAllFolders(1,2);
    }
```

This returns a JSON as below

```
    [
  {
    "folderId": 359056,
    "folderName": "BE Shared Report Inbox",
    "folderDescription": "BE Shared Report Inbox",
    },
  {
    "folderId": 359057,
    "folderName": "BE Shared Spec Inbox",
    }]
```

How could i return this as exactly as my legacy code response. I know i can convert the List to Map and display. But, is there any equivalent
way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your result into a map.

```
@GetMapping("/folders")
public List<Folder> getAllFolders() {
    return Service.findAllFolders(1,2);
    }
```

Change to:

```
@GetMapping("/folders")
public Map<String,List<Folder>> getAllFolders() {
    Map<String,List<Folder>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("folders",Service.findAllFolders(1,2));
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I know that, i am thinking of any spring feature added to get like this

Comment: Answer is no, spring convert your result to json, so if you use list, there is no way to output like you expected.